# PubNub - iOS - Carthage only?

Tags: ios, pubnub, carthage

Question for someone who's quite fresh with PubNub and iOS-Swift,

as of today can you put PubNub in a project, entirely, absolutely ***not using*** cocoapods in any way?  So, pure Carthage?

(PubNub's own doco is a little confused on the matter, at a quick glance.)

(Strictly iOS 10, no legacy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk#carthage) looks pretty clear about how to use Carthage way of integration. 
To run this command you don't need CocoaPods (platform can be any: *macos*, *tvos*, *ios* and *watchos* or w/o platform to build all):

```
carthage update --platform ios
```

The only thing is required is [Cartfile](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#cartfile) at the same directory from which you will call command from above. It should contain at leas this line (depending from version which you need):

```
github "pubnub/objective-c" ~> 4.1
```

As result you will get **.framework** bundle under `Carthage/Build/{platform-name}/PubNub.framework`. As mentioned in docs you can *drag&drop* it into your project and don't forget to add it to **Embedded Binaries**.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the project builds standalone frameworks, so you could add it as a Carthage dependency.

Carthage just downloads the project and builds it according to the project settings. All the consuming project needs to do is add the specific built product to you project.